# How do I select a TreeNode by name?

Tags: c#, treeview

The following code does not run as rootNode is null when retrieved by name "RootNode"

```
 treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("RootNode"));

 ...
 //get the rootNode by its name
 TreeView1 rootNode = treeView1.Nodes["RootNode"]

 //rootNode is null so following line throws an error
 rootNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("ChildNode"));
```

What am I missing here? How can I get a particular node by it's name??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TreeNode constructor does not accept a key / name parameter.  The indexer is based on the tree node's name, not its text.  Therefore you either need to set the tree node's name or use a different add method like this:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("RootNode", "Root Node");
```